# No such file or directory error - android studio

Tags: java, android

I have a file named boot.txt in my external storage and i want to read it but the value is coming null.

This is my code. PLease someone help me.
`private void readFile() {
// Check if external storage is available
if (isExternalStorageReadable()) {
File textFile = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "boot.txt");

```
        try {
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(textFile));
            StringBuilder text = new StringBuilder();
            String line;

            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                text.append(line);
                text.append('\n');
            }
            br.close();

            // Now text contains the content of boot.txt, you can use it as needed
            bootFileContent = text.toString();
            showToastLong("read file content: " + bootFileContent);
            // Do something with the file content

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Toast.makeText(this, "Error reading file", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(this, "External storage not readable", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

`

Comment: Use textFile.exists() and textFile.canRead() before you try to .. read.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure this,
File Path: Ensure that textFile is pointing to the correct path of the text file you want to read. If the file path is incorrect or the file doesn't exist, you'll get null when attempting to read from it.

File Permission: Make sure that your app has the necessary permissions to read external storage. You might need to request the READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission in your Android manifest file and also request it at runtime if your app targets Android 6.0 (API level 23) or higher.

Exception Handling: It's good that you have the IOException catch block, but it's also important to handle other potential exceptions like FileNotFoundException separately.

```
try {
    if (isExternalStorageReadable()) {
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(textFile));
        StringBuilder text = new StringBuilder();
        String line;

        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            text.append(line);
            text.append('\n');
        }
        br.close();

        // Now text contains the content of boot.txt, you can use it as needed
        bootFileContent = text.toString();
        showToastLong("Read file content: " + bootFileContent);
        // Do something with the file content
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(this, "External storage not readable",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    Toast.makeText(this, "File not found", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    Toast.makeText(this, "Error reading file",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}

private boolean isExternalStorageReadable() {
    String state = Environment.getExternalStorageState();
    return Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED.equals(state) || 
    Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED_READ_ONLY.equals(state);
}
```